# Html Text box only allow numeric while typing thousand separator and decimal

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i want to allow html text box accept numeric value only and while typing it should transform like thousand separator and two decimal

Example :

```
12,343.50
```

Comment: you can use the jquery library https://github.com/customd/jquery-number. or you can make your own library and listen the keydown of the text box and format the number as string.

Comment: First of all, i don't see anything related to react and second please provide what you tried so far?

Comment: @Md.AtiqulIslam jQuery?? What for? This is just number manipulation

Comment: Please don't do this, it's seriously annoying. Wait for the user to finish typing before formatting whatever it is they entered.

Comment: I tried this regex ^0$|^[1-9]\d*$|^\.\d+$|^0\.\d*$|^[1-9]\d*\.\d*$

Comment: @JeremyThille no just get an idea. its a pretty simple task.

Comment: @RobG The post has been edited by the OP himself...

Comment: I'm developing a reactjs application so that i mentioned

Comment: @Md.AtiqulIslam Precisely... this doesn't explain why jQuery is needed for this. There isn't even any DOM manipulation. Besides, OP is using React, not jQuery.

Comment: @JeremyThille—my comment is addressed to the OP.

Comment: So I didn't get it (and I still don't get it)

Comment: can anyone suggest me a regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have wrote a javascript function. You can use this to convert to commas.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="x1" onkeydown="numberWithCommas(this)"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(x.value.lastIndexOf(".")!=x.value.length-1){
      var a = x.value.replace(",","");
      var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(); 
      console.log(nf.format(a));
      x.value = nf.format(a);
    }
  },1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this the input text field will not allow any characters except numbers and value of input field will be like Indian Currency.

```js
$("#formattedNumberField").on('keyup', function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
    $(this).val(n.toLocaleString("en-IN", { currency: "INR"}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="formattedNumberField" value="" />
```

And Please refer the above Code Snippet Link.

Thanks.